# Missing Font in Apache

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I have a tex file that compiles from the command line when I run pdflatex. However, when I run the same command from PHP/Apache, I get a fatal error. I also get a file called "missfonts.log" produced, which contains the following:

```
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ecsi0800
```

In my output log, these are the last two lines:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ecsi0800): Font ecsi0800 at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I don't know what `ecsi0800` refers to - it's not in my tex file anywhere.

I've tried various permutations of updmap and updmap-sys, with no change. I can see a whole load of map files in my texmf-var directory, but no idea what to do with them to make them available to the builder.

I'm not sure if this is a server config issue or a pdflatex issue. Is it possible to tell pdflatex to use fonts from a specific location?

**Edit**: Another question led me to the command `kpsewhich pdftex.map`, with the output:

```
$HOME/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
```

So, I created a folder called $HOME with a soft link from .texmf-var to the .texmf-var folder in my home folder, and the thing works! This isn't a great solution, and I'm sure there's a better way, so please do help if you can!

Comment: How are TeX and the fonts installed on this system? Distribution-maintained packages, installing TeX Live from upstream media, or what? I suspect you have at least a few things installed in your account that aren't available to other users, including the Apache user.

Comment: All from distro, Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: You probably have run `updmap` from your account, which is usually bad. However `kpsewhich pdftex.map` will never show `$HOME` in its output, so I guess something *very* wrong has been done to your distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my build process onto a fresh install of Ubuntu and still had the same problem. In the end I installed the "texlive-full" package, and that sorted it out.